# Spark: Saving filtered rows in FilterFunction

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I've written a FilterFunction in Spark to filter rows from a DataSet. It's working fine but the new requirement is that I need to save all the omitted rows into a different location. What's the best way to do that?

My goal is to ensure that I don't go through the same DataSet twice; once to filter out rows that I want & once to get the omitted rows.

Is it possible to do that? I guess, I don't have to use a FilterFunction if there's another way.

```
public class MyFilterFunction implements FilterFunction<Row> {
    
    @Override
    public boolean call(Row row) {
        boolean filter = false
        // Some business logic here
        return filter; 
    }
}
```

Comment: can you provide sample filter condition that you are using , and for your problem solution you can create two dataframe, one dataframe with filter condition and another with Not filter condition(!(condition)). Please let me know if you want any lead in that.

Comment: Wouldn't this go thru the original DataSet twice? This is what I pointed out as my "goal" for not to do! Please see above.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of filter function, write an user defined function which will add an additional column 'partition' based on the filter condition. Actual data - data, Filter data - omitted. And then write the df using partitioner on partition column.

```
+----+----------------+---------+
|col1|filtercondition |partition|
+----+----------------+---------+
|   a|            true|     data|
|   b|           false|  omitted|
+----+----------------+---------+
//Output
//hdfs://..../data/    //Actual Data
//hdfs://..../omitted/ //Filtered Data
```

Comment: So in this case we will still go thru the original DataSet 2 times, right? Once to add a new column and then to partition it. I want to just go thru the DataSet once 'cause it is BIG! Am I missing something?

Comment: It could be done in a single iteration using user-defined function, instead of filtercondition  directly add the partition column. Could you share or elaborate on what exactly filter condition are you applying?

Comment: Added code to the original message. Can you provide code to elaborate your point?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to produce two datasets out of one. But, DataSet API doesn't provide any transformation at present (except random split, which won't solve your problem).